# android in-app testing the user is not eligible for this purchase

Tags: android, in-app

i am trying to implement the `in-app` but i get this message `**the user is not eligible for this purchase**` from google play, but i just created the test account and add it to my merchant account. (apk is in Draft so i need a test account for test)**Gmail accounts with testing access**.

i want to know that dose this process require some time(if then how much ?) `or` it just apply when i change it.

can any one help me in this.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747736/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-in-app-billing

Comment: Another "surprice" from google iab :-/ In my case google update test account list in 2 hours