# Android in app billing version 2 "User is not eligible for this purchase"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I understand this question is asked earlier but with no proper answer. I integrated v2 in-app billing a few months ago and released the app with working IAB but now I am trying to replicate exactly the same functionality in my new app with exactly the same billing code as it is part of my library project.

I have completed all the requirements to test the billing

1. uploaded an app as a draft
2. created pricepoints and set them as published
3. added a test account in settings
4. Used the new public key as it is now per app basis instead of per account basis.
5. waited more than 24 hours now

but still I am getting this error message "User is not eligible for this purchase"

here is the what I get in the log

```
CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=PURCHASE_FAILED, code=-1, permissionCode=16, message=User is not eligible for this purchase.
```

does anyone knows what does code=-1 and permissionCode=16 means?

"user is not eligible..." message is very generic and doesn't give much to the developer to solve the issue.

Comment: dupe of : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13822152/794088

Comment: you haven't read my complete question. I asked for what does code=-1 and permissionCode=16 means? Is that still dup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. There is some problem in the "New Design" of Developer Console. I deleted the apk and created a new app from "old design" and it worked. Price points(In-App products) got automatically added again as the app package name is exactly the same as old one I deleted.

Also make sured the new public key is used which is app specific now.