# Android inapp : error while retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-5:AEC-0]

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm trying to add in-app buying in an android application.

It's working using test items.

Now I'm trying to use real items. Draft is uploaded on PlayStore, items created and activated, gmail testing account has been added to testers emails, but everytime I want to buy item on my phone (with signed apk), I got this error : "**Error while retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-5:AEC-0]**"

and in the logs :

> E/Volley(14681): [967] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.flirtymob.androidv2:test_product

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it takes around 2-3 hours, so wait for some time 
refer this 
[User is not eligible for this purchase - in app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747736/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-in-app-billing) 

in one of the answer they have mention all required steps, make sure you are following all.