# User is not eligible for this purchase in app purchase version3

Tags: java, android

I want to implement the In-App purchase-v3 in my application but I always get a message User is not eligible for this purchase. I published some products on Google play 3 days before and also use the license Key provided by Google when I create the account.
But I always get the same response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User is not eligible for this purchase - in app billing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747736/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-in-app-billing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.
I provide original credit card details while purchasing the product.
Amount will not deduct from my account because I upload my app in beta testing mode.