# Why GPS based android app is not installing in Assisted-GPS (A-GPS) based android device?

Tags: android, service, gps, bootcompleted

It shows, Error states that "No eligible devices for app install"

Device specification is as follows,

Model : Lenovo A369i

Android OS Ver : 4.2.2

I am doing below permission in android mainfest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ylogtrack.activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

plz suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747736/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-in-app-billing

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan, what it means?

Comment: where does this error occur?

Comment: I am using location client to get current location. In any device which have A-GPS functionality like LENOVO A369i , not giving proper location at given time interwal.

Comment: pls post whole manifest with min and target versions

Comment: @Teekam What are you asking is not clear to me, you first said your app is not installing in the question and in the message you are saying that you are not getting proper location at interval..Explain a bit more clearly

Comment: Check your Minimum SDK VERSION `android:minSdkVersion` in your manifest? and make sure to have our max set android:targetSdkVersion to 19 (the latest version) eg. <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the specs found at [GSM Arena - Lenovo A369i](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a369i-5850.php) it states:

```
A-GPS support only
```

What that means it that the device doesn't have a distinct GPS component and is dependent on the mobile network for location.

The permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Actually implies that a GPS is available and you could get location information without a network.

```
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION requires android.hardware.location.gps and android.hardware.location
```

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features

Since the store checks the permission and the device doesn't have GPS, your app is not visible.

Try adding to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

And see if that resolves the problem.